# Template literals 60% keyboards

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Recently I bought a 60% keyboard (redragon draconic) and I really need the template literals to work on web programming.

By templates literals I mean: ``` `` ```

Question:

> **how to use template literals on 60% keyboards?**

Preview of the keyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the manual for the redragon keyboards alot of them mention FN + ESC or FN + Shift + ESC. Here is some links below for the manuals/Shortcut keys they contain.

[Redragon 60% Keyboard](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2695/9506/files/K630RGB_User_Manual.pdf?v=1620800721)

[Your 60% Redragon](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2695/9506/files/Redragon_K599_Keyboard.pdf?v=1620378223)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer works :)